# React/Flux integration test with karma: How to reload application before each test

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, karma-runner, reactjs-flux, flux

I am working on a **Browserify React/Flux** application and I want to have some sort of UI integration test for it. That is, using real components and only stub the ajax call.

The problem that I have at the moment is that after each test the stores are left initialised with data and so the next test that runs will fail because of an invalid initial state of the stores.

I would like each test to find a fresh new React application.

Is there a way to restart/reload the React+Flux application before each test when using **karma + jasmine + browserify**?

------- EDIT 1:
I am using **Jest** for unit tests, but for integration tests I want to use something closer to a real browser than jsdom.

For that I am using **PhantomJs with Karma**.

The tests are quite simple:

```
describe('Dashboard component', function () {

    afterEach(function () {
        clearAjaxStubs();
    });

    it('initializes the OrgStore when mounted and sets the state properly',
     function() {

        stubAjaxCall(require('./Dashboard-contract.json'));


        let dashboard = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
             <Dashboard params={{orgId: 'org123'}}/>
        );

        executeAllTimers();

        expect(dashboard.state.orgData.data).toEqual({name: 'orgName'});

    });

});
```

Basically, when the Dashboard component is mounted it will make an ajax call (for which I created a stub) and will initialise the OrgStore with the server response using the flux data flow. Then the component is notified when the OrgStore changes and the component state is updated.

The test works perfectly when I only run this one.

The issue appears when there is more than one: The next test will find OrgStore already initialised with the data that this test put in there.

That is why I want to restart the React application before each test.

Comment: Are you actually targeting the browser?  Like a web driver test? Or are you using React TestUtils to render? An example test might be nice.

Comment: @DavinTryon Yes, I am targeting PhantomJs. It is not a web driver test, I am using Karma test runner to run the test in PhantomJs. I have added an example and some more explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do exactly the same thing. I think this will work:

```js
  beforeEach(function() {
    AppDispatcher = require('../../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
    TodoStore = require('../TodoStore');
    callback = AppDispatcher.register.mock.calls[0][0];
  });
```

(From: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/09/24/testing-flux-applications.html#putting-it-all-together)

What they're doing here is re-requiring the App modules before each test, which in theory should reset the store (which is the major issue everyone seems to be having).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but your solution does not apply to my case. I am not using Jest, I am using Karma and PhantomJs. Jest wouldn't have this problem because every require in a jest test case would return a fresh copy of the module. With Karma and PhantomJs, the sources are loaded once and all the test suite is run using the same module instances. That is why the stores are not cleared out after each test. @theloniusmonkey